# DEVELOPER_ERROR when logging in with @react-native-google-signin in released app on Android?

Tags: android, react-native, google-signin

Everything works ok, when Im developing, but after releasing the application, or installing the app from created apk Im getting this error, what may be the reason?
Should I provide SHA-1 from release.keystore separately from debug.keystore?

Comment: provide SHA-1 from App signing on your Google Developer account for that app

Comment: there's many step to do when enabling google login, create auth screen, client id web and android, at which step when error occur?

Comment: I know that there are many steps and all of them are done correctly and the fact the Sign in works in development, proves that.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: release.keystore should also be added.